# Integrate XSLTForms in vb.net web forms

Tags: vb.net, xforms, xsltforms

I am trying to collect information for my next project where I have to use XSLTForms in vb.net web forms.

Can you suggest me some complete example about this (even if the server language is different)?

I started to read about XSLTForms but for me the integration of them in VB.net is not clear yet. The functionalities I will have to implement are the normal CRUD operations.

One of the doubts is why to use an xform processor (in my case XSLTForms ) instead of doing a simple XSLT - Transformation like

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"     runat="server">
<asp:Xml DocumentSource="cdcatalog.xml" TransformSource="cdcatalog.xsl" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

where I specify the XSL Style Sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, XSLTForms is designed for generating a full HTML page (head and body) using an XSLT transformation.

First, VB.Net can be used to perform this XSLT transformation which is really simple, as you said, just applying the XSLT stylesheet at server-side, if it is considered better than at client-side, or even just sending the processing instruction for that to the browser.

Then, while the form is running at client-side, HTTP submissions can occur with associated data. VB.Net will have to process raw HTTP requests. XForms does not specify any context information so authors have to prepare what is needed for server treatment (including credentials).

That is exactly what is done for XSLTForms+PHP.

Comment: 1.Are you meaning that the xform model ca not be included on body tag ? On examples I saw about xform the model was always in head but i was thinking i can put it also in body to use master pages.

Comment: 2. Do you mean is no need to use a 3'rd part  xform processor (XSLTForms ) if I use VB because the transformation can be made by VB code? In my mind the answer for this question is Yes, but on customer specifications I was asked to use VB + XSLTForms
I am not sure about the customer knowledge about xforms. I think he ask to use it because the object will be saved as xml.
At this moment I think the best aproach will be to use XSLT transformation made by VB .

Comment: 1. XSLTForms has to be slightly modified to generate tags to be included in master pages. Another possibility would be to use iframes

Comment: 2. XSLTForms is a two-part product: an XSLT stylesheet and a Javascript engine

Comment: Thank you Alain for your answers. The conclusion I arrived is to avoid to use xforms in this project. I will leave this Question open, just in case somebody can share a full integration of XSLTForms  in asp.net

Comment: Alain, after your last comment i feel like i miss something about xForms. Why you say is very simple and fast to build the forms after the xForms integration?  I still have to specify the xf Layout for each xf Model and this is egual to write my own  XSL Style Sheet.

Comment: XForms is not similar to XSLT. XForms has its own engine to dynamically populate data according to user interactions, whether at local side or in AJAX mode, especially with the Javascript part of XSLTForms. XForms is managing the form following complex constraints, conditions and calculations in a declarative approach. In fact, the layout is almost the only remaining part because all the logicals are automatically coordinated.